# Question about topological properties of $\Bbb{C}_p$

Tags: general-topology, p-adic-number-theory, descriptive-set-theory

It is known that the structure of $p$-adic integers, $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is homeomorphic to the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), and $\Bbb{Q}_p$ is homeomorphic to the one-point deleted Cantor set (as I know, I don't certain it.) In particular, $\Bbb{Z}_p\cong\Bbb{Z}_q$ and $\Bbb{Q}_p\cong\Bbb{Q}_q$ even if $p$ and $q$ are distinct.

My question is:

1. Is $\Bbb{C}_p\cong\Bbb{C}_q$ even if $p$ and $q$ are distinct?
2. Since $\Bbb{C}_p$ is separable and a complete metric space by the metric given by $p$-adic norm, $\Bbb{C}_p$ is a [Polish space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space). Are there well-known Polish spaces which are (topologically) homeomorphic to $\Bbb{C}_p$? (For example, $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, and Cantor set is a well-known Polish space.)

(If the tags of this question are inadequate, please tell me about it.)

Comment: When you write $cong$, do you mean homeomorphic? And when you write "$\Bbb Z_p\cong\Bbb Z_q$ unless $p$ and $q$ are distinct", do you mean $\Bbb Z_p\cong\Bbb Z_p$ but $\Bbb Z_p\not\cong\Bbb Z_q$ when $p\ne q$?

Comment: @GregMartin I confuse the word 'unless' and 'even if' :(. I modify it. I intend $\cong$ as 'these two spaces are homeomorphic.'

Comment: I understand now! Though I don't know the answer....

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{C}_p$ separable?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't know the proof of it. I found it from [this lecture note](http://pucuch.mat.uc.cl/docume/100304120442.pdf).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It is a metric space, hence separable.

Comment: @Circonflexe Not all metric spaces are separable.

Comment: Ah, oops, I read "separated" and not "separable", sorry. Separability is not much harder however: you only need to prove that $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ is separable (and then conclude by a diagonal argument). Separability of $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ means that the root of a limit of polynomials is a limit of the root of the individual polynomials, which should be easy enough to see on the Newton polygons.